# Issues trying to debug a kernel vmcore

Tags: linux, crash

One of our clients called us saying they had had a kernel crash and asked us to investigate. They are running SLES12 SP2.

I copied the `vmcore` file under `/var/crash` (11 Mb) out of production, onto another machine also running SLES12 SP2. I copied the image of the kernel `/boot/vmlinux-4.4.120-92.70-default.gz` too. I installed the kernel debuginfo package in this machine. However I'm unable to run the `crash` utility on it:

```
$ strings vmcore |grep "4\.4\."
4.4.120-92.70-default                                   
OSRELEASE=4.4.120-92.70-default                         
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.120-92.70-default root=[…]

$ strings ~/vmlinux-4.4.120-92.70-default |grep "4\.4\."
Linux version 4.4.120-92.70-default (geeko@buildhost) (gcc version 4.8.5 (SUSE Linux) ) #1 SMP Wed Mar 14 15:59:43 UTC 2018 (52a83de)

$ crash /usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-4.4.120-92.70-default.debug ~/vmlinux-4.4.120-92.70-default vmcore
crash 7.1.5
[…]
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6
[…]
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"...

WARNING: could not find MAGIC_START!
WARNING: cannot read linux_banner string
crash: /usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-4.4.120-92.70-default.debug and vmcore do not match!

Usage: […]
```

I think the `strings` invocations above prove that the kernel and the core do match, however I'm still getting that error. What can I do next?